# Adding service reference to SOAP service does not generate async methods

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, windows-store-apps, wcf-client

in metro style app I want to add service reference [(wikispaces)](http://www.wikispaces.com/page/api?wsdl). VS2012 properly discovers service:
[image: Adding service reference]

Unfortunately, the generated **Reference.cs** do not provide any methods from service:
[image: Object Browser]

Why it happens? Is this service incompatible? How can I access service?

Edit:
It's metro style app, so **async** methods should be generated. But they are not generated.

Comment: OK, WCF service proxies are called and managed differently in Windows Store apps. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556233.aspx

Comment: Anyway, according to to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556233.aspx) async operations should be generated.

Comment: Updated my answer with an alternative. Couldn't find the cause just yet. Or did you find the problem in the meantime?

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't find the cause, also. Your alternative sounds good, but there is one problem - the project is not prepared for additional WCF 4.5 service. I'cant afford for dedicated server, I do not have also a good internet connection to keep service at my home. If it is going about moving proxy class - I dont think it would be so easy. Assemblies of ServiceModel are definitely different for Winrt and full 4.5 framework. Anyway, thanks for for your effort!

Comment: I see. No problem. But if you ever find the cause, don't hesitate to drop a line here.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some more but it seems impossible to make it generate the async methods. Cannot find the exact cause. Perhaps it is something related to the WSDL.

Anyway, since you do not own the service I can only think of one way to do it. Create your own intermediate WCF 4.5 service in front of it and consume it from the app.

This will work because:

- Generating the proxy for the wikipages service works from a full framework project, so it will work from a WCF project. You could host your service in a windows service.
- It seems that generating proxies in Windows Store apps works fine for WCF services. [Example here](http://debugmode.net/2012/06/27/consuming-wcf-soap-service-in-windows-8-metro-application/).

I've also thought of generating the wikipages proxy for a full framework project and then move it to your Win8 client, but that would require correcting a lot of the generated code in order to make it compile (at least).

Comment: Object Browser shows `PagePortClient`.  There is no desired methods in there.

Comment: I was using service references couple times and I know how to do it. The problem is that there is no service methods in **PagePoartClient**

Comment: @pwas: what VS project template have you used for your app?

Comment: It's simply Windows Store App.

Answer (score 0):

Do you run VS as admin or as a normal user? I had similiar problems and running VS as admin when adding a service reference solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem with VS2012 and WikiSpaces. I don't know what's at fault exactly, but it works just fine if you [build these services from the command line](http://welltechnically.com/?p=369).

You're going to run into a second issue with WikiSpaces if you use the Messages (Comments) API. They messed up some types in their WSDL, accidentally setting body and html members to int instead of string. You'll want to either edit the WSDL and build from that, or (faster) edit the MessageService.cs that gets generated from the WSDL and make sure body and html are strings and not integers (then recompile it)!

Comment: Hey, thanks for a reply, I've already checked. Unfortunately, I'm finishing a project (I've parsed result via HtmlAgilityPack). If I had a time, I'd refactor the solution.

Answer (score 0):

pwas, in cmd.exe try this command

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0>wsdl /out:C:\wiki.cs  http://www.wikispaces.com/page/api?wsdl"
```